# glBufferData & glBufferDataARB

Tags: opengl

I found the following code:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &m_posVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_posVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(particle_attributes::POSITION, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(particle_attributes::POSITION);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &m_colorVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_colorVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(particle_attributes::COLOR, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(particle_attributes::COLOR);

glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_posVBO);
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, size, m_vPos, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_colorVBO);
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, size, m_vCol, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

I wonder why both `glBufferData()` and `glBufferDataARB()` are called respectively with one unique VBO, and what does value zero represent in `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)`?

Comment: Could you be more specific, and explain what you expected in place of a unique VBO or the null value?

Comment: @mins For example, m_posVBO is used for a parameter of glBufferData and glBufferDataARB. I think these make two buffers, and it looks odd because I think there can be only one buffer for a VBO.

Comment: @mins Additionally, I know the second parameter of glBindBuffer is VBO identification value. Is a zero valid VBO identification value?

Comment: From [glBindBuffer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml) reference: "*buffer set to zero effectively unbinds any buffer object previously bound, and restores client memory usage for that buffer object target*"

Comment: Unless you're using OpenGL 1.4 or earlier, you shouldn't need to use an ARB extension for glBindBuffer. [How extensions are provided](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Extension).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`glBufferDataARB()` and `glBufferData()` serve the same purpose. The `ARB` in the first form indicates that the entry point is part of an extension approved by the OpenGL ARB (Architecture Review Board). The second form is part of the standard OpenGL specification.

The common process is that new OpenGL features are first provided as extensions. They can then go through various stages:

- Sometimes they start as a vendor specific extension, which is indicated by them having a vendor code like `NV` as part of their name.
- If multiple vendors agree on the extension, this is indicated by an `EXT` in their name.
- If the Architecture Review Board approves the extension, the `EXT` is replaced by `ARB`.
- If the functionality becomes part of standard OpenGL, it gets added to the OpenGL spec, and the entry points have no special letter code anymore.

In your example, `glBufferDataARB()` was part of the [ARB_vertex_buffer_object extension](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_buffer_object.txt). This functionality then became part of standard OpenGL with version 1.5. Which was a long, long time ago (July 29, 2003).

This means that for any version 1.5 and newer, you can and should use `glBufferData()`. There is absolutely no reason to use `glBufferDataARB()` in this case.

Mixing standard and extension entry points for the same functionality is potentially problematic. In some cases, functionality is adopted as standard  exactly the way it was defined in the corresponding extension, and the two are equivalent. But in other cases, their might be some slight adjustments in this process, or there were even multiple extensions for similar functionality that were consolidated while the functionality was added to the standard. In those cases, mixing standard and extension entry points may not work.

In summary: Don't use the extension (`ARB`) form if your OpenGL implementation has standard support for the functionality. And **never** mix standard and extension forms of the same functionality.

For the second part of your question:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

unbinds the previously bound buffer. Picture it binding a "null" buffer, similar to the way you use null pointers in C/C++ to indicate that the pointer does not point to an object.